# How to solve "useRef is not function error" in react js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am trying use rc-time-picker,but i am getting following error 
Please check below error,what i am getting
    `Align.js:88 Uncaught TypeError: 
    react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.useRef is not a 
    function
    at Align (Align.js:88)
    at updateForwardRef (react-dom.development.js:13581)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:14402)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:16627)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:16667)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:107)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:144)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:191)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:16042)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:16724)
    at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:17352)
    at performWork (react-dom.development.js:17274)
    at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:17247)
    at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:17528)
    at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2248)
    at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:4749)`

Comment: can you post your code that you tried because for me it's working

Comment: Actually for me also it is working for new web app(react-version:16.12),after that I tried to add my project,at that time it is gettting issue(react-version: 16.4)

Answer (score 6):

> useRef is a React Hook It was introduced only in React 16.8.

Upgrade your React (and React DOM) to anything after 16.8 and try again.

Sources : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

> "Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class." -FROM THE DOCS

Answer (score -2):

make sure you imported the useRef dependency from React

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).